# Android monkeyrunner - drag method from MonkeyDevice does long-press instead of screen flicking

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

The drag method from Monkeyrunner always does the long-press incorrectly instead of the screen flicking/swiping.

```
device.drag((762,1796),(341,1796), 0.01, 50)
```

Is there a way to workaround this issue without disabling long-press in the test app itself?

Comment: This question is valid. It's incorrectly marked as off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the device, but if you are getting a long-press instead of drag try increasing the number of steps and duration, for example:

```
device.drag((762,1796),(341,1796), 0.5, 50)
```

Comment: Thank you. I increased the duration and steps.  I am still getting a long-press intermittently.